# Facebook, if user "liked" ("subscribed"), then don't do popup window (rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have Ruby on Rails app and we are using Facebook to promote our app. We already have like buttons to our page and other FB features. Already registered in FB.developer.

But we are having bad callback to subscribe to our page, so we want to add popup window (we don't want to impose subscription). And there is two possibility to do it:

**First** (not the best one), when user visiting out app (site) give him a cookie. If user don't have cookie - make popup, if user have cookie - don't popup. Pretty simple solution.

**Second** (the best one), when user visit our app, we check: "is user already liked out FB page". If liked - don't do popup, opposite - do popup.

I know how to do first variant, but I don't have any ideas how to do second. The main question - "How to check is user like page or not?"

Comment: Like Gating is not allowed any more by Facebook. They won’t grant your app the use of the necessary permission to read a user’s likes for such a purpose anyway.

Comment: So the only way is to send cookie?